# Primefaces skip form validation on button

Tags: primefaces, validation

I'm developing a wizard using primefaces, the last step of the wizard is optional. But if they do wish to fill in the last step some fields are required.

I gave the user 2 buttons, 1 to save including the last step and 1 button to save the previous steps and ignore the last step.

So I need to skip the validation when clicked on the second button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this was to add `process="@this"` to the second button.